# End Sub which was called when ActiveX button was toggled to True

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook with 15 macros and a specific macro 'Launch_Time1' runs all of them one by one in a sequence on given time. I have created an ActiveX toggle button which calls Launch_Time1 when it's pressed.

The problem with my code is that when the button is clicked ON and then back to OFF, the code still triggers the macro on that given time. When it should not have run. I assume the trigger command was stored somewhere in memory and did not clear when button is off. Can you tell how to stop it when the button is not pressed?

This also creates a problem of multiple runs if pressed ON and Off more than once.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        ToggleButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 18").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 12").Visible = False
        Call Launch_Timer1.Launch_Time1
    Else
        ToggleButton1.BackColor = RGB(255, 102, 102)
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 18").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 12").Visible = True
    End If
    End Sub
```

Here is the sub this button calls when pressed.

```
Sub Launch_Time1()
    Application.OnTime TimeSerial(7, 0, 0), "Launcher1"
End Sub

    Private Sub Launcher1()

    If Weekday(Now, vbMonday) < 6 Then

         Application.Speech.Speak "Autobot is launching daily routine sequence."

         Call CodeSet_0_EnCash_Refresh.EnCash_Refresh
         Call CodeSet_2_Selenium_BRR.Selenium_BRR
         Call CodeSet_3_EnCash_RAW_Americas.EnCash_Daily_RAW_Americas
         Call CodeSet_4_EnCash_RAW_Asia.EnCash_Daily_RAW_Asia
         Call CodeSet_5_EnCash_RAW_Europe.EnCash_Daily_RAW_Europe
         Call CodeSet_6_EnCash_RAW_Japan.EnCash_Daily_RAW_Japan
         Call CodeSet_7_MasterFile.EnCash_Daily_Master
         'Call CodeSet_9_Performance_Report_QC.Performance_Report

         Application.Speech.Speak "Autobot has finished daily routine sequence. Restaring the Timer"

    Else

    End If
         Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
         Call Launch_Time1

    End Sub
```

Comment: The given code does not suffice to reproduce the problem. (1) Creating a new file, (2) inserting an ActiveX toggle button, (3) and copying your code into the toggle button (removing the lines regarding the shapes and the sub call) works as expected and there is no problem / error. So, the problem must be somewhere in the sub you are calling. But creating a new Excel sheet and copying your code works without a problem. So, unless you can allow us to reproduce the problem there is no way we can help you.

Comment: @Ralph I have edited my question and added those codes in that sub. Actually that also calls more subs at 7 AM every morning and then loops except weekends.

Comment: possible hack to stop the behavior while you find something more elegant is to store a variable in your worksheet or macros like `hasRun`. If hasRun has a value, then do not proceed with the action. When the program is launched, set the value.

Comment: Jessi, it will run everyday so saving the value in a variable doesn’t look good to me. I am just unable to understand this strange behaviour of the macro. Does clicking the button multiple times crates multiple timer event triggers in memory even if I unpress the button?